XFoil aglorithm for generating a NACA 4-digits airfoil
I need to generate NACA 4-digits airfoil points in the exact same way that XFoil software does, I need the algorithm so that I can convert it to another programming language,other than fortran...
I have looked into the source code of XFoil and found the file called "naca.f".
It does generate the airfoil, and it works fine, but it is not the same as when using the software and typing:
>> naca 2412
>> ppar n 150
>> psav naca2412.dat

The points are -simply- not the same
and the problem is that, when I apply a source-vortex panels method (implemented by me) on both the two different airfoil data, the results are within a 2% change for lift, and about 12% for moment, (for the same panels method code), which is quite unacceptably large.
So I really need to know how does XFoil exactly generate/modify the airfoil data after the subroutine "NACA4" is called.

Not sure that questions about the algorithms of a particular software package is on-topic here, even when the software itself is about aviation.

@RalphJ You aren't wrong, but once again, unfortunately there isn't an Aerospace Engineering SE and we're left to the gracious hosting of Aviation SE.

@RalphJ I know aviation is not necessarily aeronautics engineering, but I don't know any other space for that.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Not every question that can be asked will necessarily belong anywhere on Stack Exchange. That doesn't mean that the question itself is necessarily a bad question per se, just that it may not fit the SE model. Even with Aviation.SE being the closest thing actually available to a hypothetical AerospaceEngineering.SE, that doesn't mean that everything that might fit into the hypothetical latter, meets the criteria for the former. The fact that this question is being 'answered' as a back & forth, rather than with the answer to the question suggests "not a good fit for this format."
